# Restrict access between source folders in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to have the following:

```
Project/
  src-core/<packages>/<java-files>
  src-module1/<packages>/<java-files>
  src-module2/<packages>/<java-files>
```

Where both modules can access src-core, but neither src-core nor each other module can access the modules.

It is possible to achieve this using multiple projects and setting up the project dependencies accordingly, but we start having many modules and don't want to create a new project each time.

Projects also have a feature called [Access restrictions](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-WorkingWithExistingLayout6.htm) which would do just the right thing if it could be applied to source folders.

Is there any way (maybe a plugin or other trick) to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this link if you are using gradle.

https://rominirani.com/gradle-tutorial-part-3-multiple-java-projects-5b1c4d1fbd8d#.9ibawqces

Comment: I looked over it. Looks nice so far, but does it actually apply access restrictions as well? A dependency just says "i need this". But does it imply, that when i don't say "i need this" that I can not use it for sure?

Comment: You mean to say the dependency need some other module ??

Comment: No, i am asking whether the absence of a dependency to (let's say) module2 ensures that we have no access to module2, even though it is in our project.

Comment: Then it may be configuration issue.

Answer (score 2):

By using maven's [multi-module project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).

You will get compile errors if module1 uses classes of module2.